# Vue2 - How to access router from composable function

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm using [Vue Compostion API](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api), I know that I have to use `context` in `setup` function to access the props defined in Vue prototype like this:

```js
setup(props, ctx) {
  const router = cxt.root.$router
}
```

But how can I access it inside a composable function?

```js
export default useLink {
  // here to access the $router
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 3.6.0 of `vue-router`, the composables are officially supported, so you can use route like this:

```js
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router/composables'

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue2, you can pass instance or context as a parameter to the composable function. But if you are using vue3, you can just import

import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';